# Do I have to worry about the depletion of IPv4 addresses in embedded applications?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, ethernet, ipv6

We're nearing the exhaustion of IPv4. What should be my concern about it for embedded devices?

I don't know about others manufacturers but until today, Microchip TCP stack doesn't implement the IPV6.

Comment: There are still very vital servers running Windows 2000 and before. These machines usually don't ever get any OS changes on them because they don't want to risk messing up the application running on it. Because of things like this, there has been a lot of work put into trying to make ipv4 and ipv6 work side by side in order to buffer any adverse effects of the change over.

Comment: Basically, as long as we have NAT, no.

Comment: The Yaler project (http://yaler.org/) enables you to run an embedded IPv4 Web server from behind a NAT/firewall. A single Yaler relay server instance with a public IP address supports 1000's of embedded devices. (Disclosure: I work for the company developing Yaler)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

IPv4 isn't going away any time soon.
If you are concerned about IPv6 compatability, have a look at [uIP](http://www.sics.se/~adam/contiki/docs-uipv6/a01110.html/).

[Here's](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/usenet/embedded/show/99338-1.php) a thread from comp.arch.embedded about embedded IPv6 stacks.

In my experience, most embedded devices which are not explicitly for networking (routers, gateways, switches) are behind NAT. So, running out of IPv4 addresses is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that sure (like Joby).

If your device is going to live 5-15 years, the problems with IPv4 could have become worse. And at some point there is going to be a switch, IPv4 can't live forever and we can't ignore the problems forever.

But on the other hand NAT will continue to save IPv4, 
so your guess is as good as mine.

So my advice is to play it safe and at least see if there is a possibility to upgrade your device to IPv6 if you need it....

Comment: I see a gateway effect where NAT is used to map IPv4 addresses on a local domain and map them to global IPv6. This way most hardware can be kept the same locally.